# Linq compare by date problem

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My Code is here

```
VisitorLog log = db.Context.VisitorLogs
         .Where(vl=>vl.inDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

this error shown

`The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported`

How to compare by only date `(skip time)` in LINQ?

**CORRECT ANSWER**

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
VisitorLog log = db.Context.VisitorLogs
.Where(vl => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(vl.inDate, currentDate) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks for answered.

Comment: do `ToString()` on each side and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use entity canonical functions see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563%28v=vs.90%29.aspx),  and for all canonical functions see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). You can use Day, year and Month to solve your problem.

Comment: @ebattulga, I'd updated the answer, I'm not going write code, try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead,

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
VisitorLog log = db.Context.VisitorLogs
         .Where(vl=>vl.inDate.Date == currentDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this could be tricky if vl.inDate.Date includes the time, but it will not error out, just that there may not be a match

EDIT:

Given that the didn't work, can you try this work around

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
var timeIn24HrsTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;
VisitorLog log = db.Context.VisitorLogs
         .Where(vl=>vl.inDate >= currentDate && vl.inDate < timeIn24HrsTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ok, seems inDate is the Date field and you intend to get the Date part  as usual.  Linq to entity does not recognise the function that way. I will edit the answer to put a work around I believe could work

Comment: The only way could work is using canonical function, datetime functions doesn't work in linq2entity, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also:

```
context.Products.Where(x=> (
       EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedDate) >=
       EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startdate))
    && (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedDate) <=
       EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(enddate)))
```

According to your requirement 
you should try for:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;

VisitorLog log = db.Context.VisitorLogs.Where(vl =>
   EntityFunctions.DiffDays(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(vl.inDate),
   EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(currentDate)) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: 'TruncateTime' is the best way for this. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
vl.inDate.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date)
```